# Migration build succeeded but Migration folder does't appear in solution explorer

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, .net-6.0

i've goth problem with migration. I was browsing a lot, but I can't find solution.
The problem is when i create migration using `add-migration [migrationName]` command,
a Migrations folder is created but i can't see it in solution explorer, using the command `update-database` I get `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.`Also when I search the folder with my project - the migrations folder is there.  
[image: Solution Explorer - view][image: Folder with project - view]
Before this migration (the one I'm trying to do now) i deleted migration folder from project.  I also added the folder manually, but it also did not appear. Should I delete something more then only Migrations folder? This still does't resolve the issue of adding other folders... I remember last time I changed the database content in the same way and everything worked. I have read that it is possible to redirect migration files to a selected folder but due to the above mentioned problem it isn't possible and I want to fix this problem, not work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, I had to click on Show all files button in solution explorer, then right click on grayed out folder and choose include to project option.
[image: Show All Files button]
[image: Include to project - solution explorer]